# TemplateDoesNotExist Django

Tags: django, django-templates

My Django template location is listed as:

```
python\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates
```

In my view I have:

```
return render_to_response('hello.html', {'name': name})
```

When I keep the `hello.html` in this location it's working

```
python\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates
```

Though i have kept template location as

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
```

]

```
NewProject
    -NewProject
        settings.py
    -signups 
        view.py
             def hello(request):
                 name='vijay'
                 return render_to_response('hello.html',{'name':name})
    templates
        hello.html
```

Comment: Instead of saying does not work, why don't you take a good look at the stacktrace to see what it says, if you need help with that add it to the question.

Comment: @user1844634  What is django version?

Comment: just print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'), it in setings.py file and checkout on your error page where django try to find out your template folder in your project
for more:  stackoverflow.com/questions/3038459/django-template-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're defining `TEMPLATES` in your `settings.py` file, `TEMPLATE_DIRS` won't have any effect. You should move value from `TEMPLATE_DIRS` into `DIRS` sub-setting inside `TEMPLATES`.

Also, `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')` will generate path to your templates directory relative to `settings.py` file, but your templates folder is one dir above `settings.py`. That line should look like this:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'templates')
```

Quick explanation: it will take path to settings.py, get it's parent directory path, get that directory parent directory path and glue into it your folder name. So all should look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (
            os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'templates'),
        ),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Actually, path to your project directory it's already defined in default settings.py, so if you're using default one, you can simplify it to:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Check twice if your path to templates is correct. You can print it inside your `settings.py` file and run development server via `manage.py`, that will show you full path built by `os.path.join` and `os.path.dirname`.

Comment: I have added the folder structure in the main query. in the settings.py i defined TEMPLATES